spring boot except first request I get 500 error
All of my rest controllers make a request to third party web servis to get authorities.

When I try to make two request from angular to my backend (getBooks getAUthors etc. both of them make same request to the third party service. ),first request get 200 and the other one get 500 always(The only error I catch is mapper error beause of response body is null in 500).
Rarely I get 200 both of them.
in angular I tried  to make two request directly to third party webservice , all of them was succesfull. I also tried 100 request from postman directly to the web service again I get 200.
So I thought the problem was spring boot.I tried @async in spring boot and async apache client , I get same result.
Then I tried to change third party service to the other service.But I get all 200 response,so I thought maybe the problem was service again .
the only solution I found is I add syncronized to the function that make request to third part service. But the other developers told me it wasnt right solution. I am so so confused. If anybody help I am gonna pray him/her all day. Thank you.
JwtAuthenticationFilter:

@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = getTokenFromRequest(request);
        if(StringUtils.hasText(token) && jwtService.validateToken(token)){
            String username = jwtService.getUserName(token);
             //problem is here above
            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
           
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    username,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities()
            );



            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        
}

and inside of method :
SimpleHttpRequest request = SimpleRequestBuilder.get(url).addParameter("username",username)
                 .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json").addHeader("Accept","*/*").build();
         CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .build();
         client.start();
         Future<SimpleHttpResponse> future = client.execute(request, null);
         SimpleHttpResponse response = future.get();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String code = String.valueOf(response.getCode());
        List<UserAuthorityDto> authorities=objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody().getBodyText(), UserAuthorityDto.class).getAuthorities()
                .stream()collect(Collectors.toList());
         client.close();
        return   CompletableFuture.completedFuture(yetkiler);


Step 1: look for stacktraces for uncaught exceptions in your server-side log files ...

No stacktracves, apparently no relevant code that is actually being called. So impossible to answer.

@M.Deinum The only error I catch is mapper error beause of response body is null in 500

You are making 2 requests, you show only code for one. You aren't catching any errors here and the code is Java not javascript from angular. So I have no clue what this code is or how it relates to your question.

error was not about spring boot or my side. 3 party web services had its own problem.

A 500 error is caused by an exception in your code. It's hard to debug without knowing the source of the error. You should check the console of the spring boot application to see if there are any exceptions or stack trace.
The first thing I would suggest is to wrap your method in a try/catch statement and log the error so that you can get more visibility into what's going on.
For starters, just do something like:
@RestController
class MyController {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

  public Object getResult() {
    try {
      ...
      // All your code here
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
      LOGGER.error("Error executing request", e);
      // Then return an error response, or for starters we can just re-throw the exception
      throw e
    }
  }

This will help you gain more visibility into what's going wrong and allow us to help you solve the issue further (or maybe solve it yourself).
